# String.contains doing opposite Jsoup Android

Tags: android, string, jsoup

I may be misunderstanding what String.contains does. I am now trying to pull a specific link using Jsoup in Android. I'm trying to just get the faceBook one as an example. Ive tried a few things. this one It Seems to be outputting got it on the ones that do not contain the facebook url and leaving the facebook ones blank. How do I just get the FaceBook ones and stop the loop.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      Document doc = null;
         try {
             doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.homedepot.com").get();
             Elements link = doc.select("a[href]");
             String stringLink = null;

             for (int i = 0; i < link.size(); i++) {

                 stringLink = link.toString();

                 if (stringLink.contains("https://www.facebook.com/")){
                     System.out.println(stringLink+"got it");
                 }
                 else{
                 //System.out.println(stringLink+"not it");
             }
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return null;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is causing the problem:

```
stringLink = link.toString();
```

The `link` variable is a collection of Elements (in this case every link on the page), so by calling `link.toString()` you're getting the String representation of every single link on the page all at once! That means `stringLink` will always contain the facebook link!

Change the line to:

```
stringLink = link.get(i).toString();
```

This line gets only the link at index i on each iteration and checks whether or not it contains the facebook link.